# Why am I getting an empty pointer when dequeuing in FreeRTOS?

Tags: c, pointers, task-queue, freertos

I need to send some ascii character strings from one task to another.

I need to send not the string but the address of the first character (as a reference to the string) to another task. The reason I want to send "a reference" to the string and not the string is because I may have a string as long as 250 characters, or maybe more, and I don't want the queue send routine to be copying all the 250+ characters every time a message has to be sent.

As I'm dealing with shared memory then there is no problem about sending pointers and this is a more efficient approach since the FreeRTOS queue send routine just copies 4 bytes (the size of the pointer to the first characters from the string to be sent) instead the n characters in the string.
The function for sending this messages is as follows:

```
static char* msg_location = NULL; /* global memory so its contents doesn't corrupt */

void TR_Trace(const char *const string)
{
  size_t stringSize = 0;

  /* Get the string size to create the dinamyc memory storage */
  stringSize = strlen(string);

  msg_location = pvPortMalloc(stringSize + 1);

  /* Now copy the text to the newly created buffer */
  strcpy(msg_location, string);

  System_Events_Send_to_Task(SYSTEM_TASK_TR_Trace_Task,
                             TR_EV_SEND_TRACE_MSG,
                             msg_location, sizeof(char *));
}
```

The "System_Events_Send_to_Task" is a system task I created and I use it to send events to any task. Since the events may have data then this routine helps to abstract the process. Don't pay attention to everything as I just put this for you to see this "intermediate" step in the character string sending.

```
bool System_Events_Send_to_Task(System_Tasks_T dest_task,
                            System_Events_IDs_T event_id,
                            void *data, size_t size)
{
  bool event_sent = false;
  portBASE_TYPE send_status;
  System_Event_T event;   

  if(NULL != System_Queue_Handles_Array[dest_task])
  {
    /* Fill the system event struct with the data from the parameters */
    event.event_id  = event_id;
    event.data      = data;
    event.data_size = size;

    /* Send the event to the selected Events Queue */
    send_status = xQueueSend(System_Queue_Handles_Array[dest_task],
                             &event,
                             (QUEUE_SEND_WAIT_TIME / portTICK_RATE_MS));

    /* Check if the event was sent */
    if (pdPASS == send_status)
    {
      event_sent = true;
    }
    else
    {
      event_sent = false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    /* If the queue is not created yet then the transfer is signaled as failed */
    event_sent = false;
  }

  return event_sent;
}
```

Ok then, the problem I'm facing is that in the receiving task I'm getting an "Invalid Address" when triyng to get the address sent in the "TR_Trace" routine. I get this Invalid address error when single stepping in the debug session.
Here is the way I'm trying to recover the address.

```
void TR_Trace_Task(void *pvParameters)
{
  System_Event_T bb_event; /**< Variable to read the events received by the task */
  char* temp_ptr;

  ...

  while(1)
  {
    xQueueReceive(TraceMessageQueue, &bb_event, portMAX_DELAY);

    switch (bb_event.event_id)
    {
      case TR_EV_SEND_TRACE_MSG:
      {
        temp_ptr = (char*)bb_event.data; /* THE PROBLEM IS HERE! */

        strcpy(DMATxBuffer, (const char *)temp_ptr);

        DmaChnStartTxfer(TRACE_TX_DMA_CHANNEL, DMA_WAIT_NOT, TX_TRANSMISSION_RETRIES);

        /* The memory allocated and being pointed to by the var "temp_ptr"
         * is freed */
        vPortFree((void *)temp_ptr);

        break;
      }

      default:
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

When I debug I'm noticing that if I put a break point at **temp_ptr = (char*)bb_event.data;** the debugger shows that the **.data** is empty and I don't know why.

Any Ideas?

Regards.

Comment: Maybe because it's empty.

Comment: TL;DR. But passing a pointer from one task to another? even if the memory is shared it may be "mounted" at a different address...

Comment: no it's not. I checked the variables and in the "event.data" contain a valid address and "event.data_size" is equal to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any red flags, few things to check.

1. Make sure your queue that was created is using the same System_Event_T struct.
2. Make sure System_Queue_Handles_Array[dest_task] is passing to the TraceMessageQueue queue.
3. Check that pvPortMalloc(stringSize + 1) is not returning NULL or some weird memory location.

Comment: I'll choose this as the answer because your 1st comment made me to check the queue creation and I found out that the size of the queued element was wrong. I had sizeof(char *) instead of sizeof(System_Event_T), this, because originally I had been sending the address directly instead the System_Event_T struct and when making the change I forgot to change that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is subtly different to the code you posted on the FreeRTOS support forum, where it was suggested the cause was that you were queuing the address of a pointer, rather than the value of the pointer.  Which code is giving the problem - the code here on the code on the other forum - as the code here does not seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Both have the problem. After the suggestion from the answer in the FreeRTOS forum I made this change and still having the same issue.